# Find the first ancestor node with X attribute using XPath

Tags: html, xml, xpath

I have duplicate nested structures in my DOM and I am trying to find certain input elements at the current node level.

For example, say the current node was `<div data-model="user" data-id="1">`. How could I get the the `<input value=foo` without getting the `<input value=bar` (since it's under it's own `data-model`)?

```
<div>
    <div data-model="user" data-id="1">
        <div>
            <input data-field="email" value="foo">

            <div data-model="user" data-id="2">
                <div>
                    <input data-field="email" value="bar">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is what I have in an xpath so far:

```
//*[@data-model="user"]//*[@data-field and ancestor::*[@data-model="user" ....]]
```

Comment: Your title says ancestor but your question appears to be looking for the first _descendant_ satisfying particular constraints. What exactly are the criteria - do you just want the first descendant input (`descendant::input[1]`) or do you want all inputs under this div that are not inside a deeper data-model?

Comment: And can you use XPath 2.0 or are you restricted to 1.0?

Comment: I would like all inputs under this div which are not under their own div further down the tree. I am limited to 1.0 - but I can make multiple passes with an external language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it in two steps. First evaluate

```
count(ancestor-or-self::div[@data-model = 'user'])
```

*as a number*, with the current div as the context node. Then take that number `$n` and evaluate

```
.//input[count(ancestor::div[@data-model = 'user']) = $n]
```

The idea here is to find all descendant input elements that have the same number of containing `data-model="user"` divs as the context node we started from (inclusive).

From XSLT you could do this in a single pass because you have access to the `current()` function which lets you "escape" from the predicate

```
.//input[count(ancestor::div[@data-model = 'user']) = 
  count(current()/ancestor-or-self::div[@data-model = 'user'])]
```

This function isn't available in pure XPath but if your library lets you pass variable bindings to your expressions then you could provide the context node in a variable and use that in place of `current()`.